# Reducing file size of animated Plotly Express Choropleth plot

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I am plotting numerical data using `plotly` Express `Choropleth` and that data has changing values over time, which makes an animation sensible to use. The resulting file size is, however, quite large and I would like to reduce it for web applications.

The problem seems to be that Plotly saves the underlying geojson for each animation frame separately to the HTML-file. Is there a way to let Plotly reuse the single geojson for all animation frames?

**What I tried, but had insufficient effect:**

- Reduce the accuracy with which the coordinates of the Polygons are saved
- Reduce the number of animation frames (but that is no option long-term)

**The code I am using is:**

```
    fig = px.choropleth(df,
                        geojson=regionalized_data,
                        locations=df['statistische_kennziffer'],
                        color=df[disp_value],
                        featureidkey='properties.ARS',
                        fitbounds='locations',
                        hover_data=hover_data_present,
                        labels=readable_labels_local,
                        animation_frame=df['Inbetriebnahmemonat'] if 'Inbetriebnahmemonat' in df.columns else None,
                        animation_group=df['statistische_kennziffer'] if 'Inbetriebnahmemonat' in df.columns else None,
                        basemap_visible=False,
                        )
```

But I do not expect this to really change anything with regards to my question.

Comment: Please refer to the reference for [information](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/#full-parameter-documentation) on reducing html file size.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my question as it does not detail how to make plotly reuse coordinates and just provides other tips such as the external loading of libraries to reduce file size.

Comment: Why don't you post to [this community](https://community.plotly.com/), as a good skilled person may be able to answer your question.

Comment: How are you saving it? As an image? As HTML?  If you're saving it as HTML, you should heed what @r-beginners mentioned. The size of Plotly.js is probably the majority of the size (not your data). If you are saving it as HTML, you only have to set `include_plotlyjs = 'cdn'` to change the size significantly. If you're saving it as an image, then reduce the size, the resolution, or both.